# How can I import files into my front end main.js files?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I'm using wordpress, javascript and html

I am using `wp_enqueue_script`

Main.js includes, one hundred lines of code, so i want to break the code up into separate files.

e.g. file 1 , file 2 , file 3.

How can i import those files into the main.js file?

I have tried using import, export statements but i get the error

```
Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

Answer (score -1):

try replacing import with require

```
// import { parse } from 'node-html-parser';
const parse = require('node-html-parser');
```

Comment: this is front end, not node.